# What does an E128 error mean on a steamist digital shower control?

Tags: plumbing, shower, steam

Every few minutes our steamist shower is turning off all water flow and displaying "`You have experienced a shower Error! E128`".  It can be restarted immediately.

The display/control is a Steamist TCS-550 ([pdf manual](https://steamist.com/wp-content/uploads/bsk-pdf-manager/2018/06/311-A_TSC-550_Operation_06_17.pdf)) and the [list of error codes](https://steamist.com/wp-content/uploads/bsk-pdf-manager/2018/06/TSC_Error_Codes.pdf) are 1 through 19 -- no 128.

It is connected to a [Steamist TSSH electric valve control](https://steamist.com/wp-content/uploads/bsk-pdf-manager/2018/06/320-D_TSSH_Install_Print_0816.pdf) and a TSG-10 steam generator.

It's a new install, so it's as likely something is connected wrong as it is that something failed.

What's causing this unlisted error?

[image: E128 on digital shower control]

Comment: Is there a manual override (faucet) you can use until you can update the firmware. (Sorry to sound so flippant, but when glitchy software/hardware prevents one from being able to shower, that's a bit too much. I would hope that there is some foolproof circuitry that would prevent the device from turning off the cold water and potentially scald an unsuspecting AI victim.)

Comment: Naw, and when the power is out it doesn't work at all. We wouldn't have put this unless we had other showers to use as backups, but "Hey, Google start the steam shower" is pretty nice (when it works).

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer's support line said the error means too much back-pressure on one of the outlets. We still got this error when only using a single outlet at 30% flow, which shouldn't be possible.

The connected TSSH shower valve is being replaced under warranty.